# Is there anyway to use an iphone/ipad as a mouse/keyboard locally (with a wire)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, mouse

In case someone lacks WirelessLAN.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps such as [Mobile Mouse Remote](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id289616509?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) available which purport to offer various HID functions over USB. (This is not an endorsement of this specific product, just an example.) Connecting over WiFi seems to be more widely requested, but searching the web still turns up several non-wireless solutions.